# DFP multi sized third party creatives

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-dfp

We usually put ads threw google DFP, we just take third party script as creative, upload it and every thing works. This particular problem ocurred whit a new third party creative that returns 3 different sizes of ads.

I have one place for mobile ad 320x50. Creative returns 320x50, 320x150, 300x50. Plus there is another creative that returns either full screen ad or some sticky ad.

Question is, where do I need to adjust my approach? In DFP? Or should I call webmasters to change style of a ad  to auto?

Answer (score 0):

Third party scripts should be able to resize the friendly iframe of your adunit if they work dynamically. You should contact the webmaster and tell that his script can indeed resize the iframe based on creative size.